# Custom Polymer elements aren't showing anymore

Tags: polymer

I updated all my Polymer elements to the latest version and now my own elements won't show anymore.

In the head:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-elements/my-test/my-test.html">
```

In the body:

```
<my-test></my-test>
```

The elements code:

```
<dom-module id="my-test">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            position: relative;
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #FFF;
        }
    </style>

    <div>Huhu</div>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-test"
    });
</script>
```

All the other elements like `<paper-checkbox></paper-checkbox>` are still working. What has changed?

Comment: Is that the full code snippet? Because you're missing a closing `dom-module` tag...The rest looks fine.

Comment: yes, I have the tag in my code, but still not working :(